# .htaccess doesn't pass arguments to url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, xampp

I was trying to make my server redirecting to a single page every request the user asks.
The way I am doing it is this:

```
# Turn rewriting on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
# Redirect requests to py-server.php if the request is that page (to avoid loops)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/py-server.php
# Check if it is not an asset that the page requested needs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.png$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.jpg$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.css$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.gif$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.js$ [NC]
# Finally, redirects to the page by adding to the URL the path originally requested
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /py-server.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I added some comments to clarify why I've written those lines.

Now, that code is made by pasting various codeblocks from the internet, but it should work from what I read around.

The fact is that the server redirects correctly to the right page, but **without the path** in the URL (= there isn't the path argument at all).

**Note**: the `.htaccess` file is located at the root directory of the site in localhost (I use XAMPP for the server); the `request` I'm referring to is, simply, the request of any file of the server like `/index.php`, `/some_dir/`, `/some_dir/index.php`;

Did I forgot something to add? or did I make a mistake anywhere?

Comment: What request are you making? Where is your `.htaccess` file located? What is your file structure? Is the `path` URL parameter set but is empty? Or is the `path` param missing altogether? "I learned that [QSA] is what is needed to append the path to the URL as a GET parameter" - no it's not. The `QSA` flag merges (appends) the original query string from the request onto the end of the query string stated in the _substitution_ string (Query String Append). Unless you are expecting a query string on the initial request then the `QSA` flag is not required here.

Comment: @MrWhite I edited the post to answer all the points of your comment. As for the `QSA` flag, I understood that while looking around, but I evidently misunderstood, I'm sorry. Now I hope that the question is clarified enough, however you can post any other comment as you want, I'll try to answer to anything you could ask ^^

Comment: Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: You didn't answer these questions in my previous comment: "What is your file structure? Is the path URL parameter set but is empty?" Are you passing actual file/directory requests to your script?

Comment: as for the question about whether the parameter is set or not, I've already answered in the post, read where I say: "The fact is that the server redirects correctly to the right page, but without the path in the URL (= there isn't the path argument at all)."; it means that the parameter didn't show up at all. Plus, my file structure wasn't really important because I wanted that the `.htaccess` could work with EVERY server file requested in the URL. Besides, the only other directives where about 404 and 500 ErrorDocument, I'm sorry, I forgot to say that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I found the solution searching here and there again:

```
# Turn rewriting on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
# Redirect requests to py-server.php if the request is that page (to avoid loops)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/py-server.php
# Check if it is not an asset that the page requested needs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.png$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.jpg$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.css$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.gif$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.js$ [NC]
# Here, this is the line that does the job!
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /py-server.php?path=%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,NC]
```

I solved by putting `%{REQUEST_URI}` as an argument for the original path to pass and the `R=302` flag between squared brackets.

All this code works perfectly, now: redirects ALL the requests to a file.php EXCEPT FOR the assets (JS files, images, GIFs, CSS files...) and the actual final file to avoid loops.

**Edit**: as MrWhite wrote in the comments, the only problem seems to have been the `R=302` flag, because `$1` and `%{REQUEST_URI}` would work in both cases with just a little difference.

Comment: But this now triggers an external redirect - that can't be desirable? (You've also removed the `L` flag - you need the `L` flag if you add any more directives.) The only difference with using the `REQUEST_URI` server variable over using the `$1` backreference in this context is that `REQUEST_URI` starts with a slash. It should not make any difference with whether the value is passed at all or not.

Comment: Well, I found the entire code in a forum with the `%{REQUEST_URI}` and `R=302`, so I solved by putting them both. If only one of them is the real solution, I didn't know that because I put them at one time. If you're right, the problem was `R=302`, and that's ok, I can edit the post. Also, I read, now, what does it do the `L` flag, and I appreciate the piece of advice, thank you!